# Data type mismatch in critera expression

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I badly need help with this:

"
**Instructions** : Implement a functionality in the form of one button (arrival, departure). Implement a case with only one button and automatically determine whether the arrival or departure (according to records in the database)"

**My goal** 
- 1.st click on button sets arrival time, 2nd click on button sets departure time and it saves it into database table - weekdays ... 
**Error that i get**
- Arrival time gets recorded, but i get error of "data type mismatch in criteria expression" when i click on the button for second time.

This is my code,

```
int counter = 0;
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;            
    DateTime arrivalTime = DateTime.Now;
    dateList.Add(arrivalTime);
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        string write = "Insert into Weekdays (Arrival) values('" + dateList[0].ToString() + "');";
        OleDbCommand read = new OleDbCommand(write, sc);
        OleDbDataReader reading;
        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            reading = read.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Arrival time saved!.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        sc.Close();
    }
    if(counter == 2)
    {
        string update = "UPDATE Weekdays SET Departure = '" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Arrival ='" +"';";
        OleDbCommand read1 = new OleDbCommand(update, sc);
        OleDbDataReader reading1;
        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            reading1 = read1.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Departure time saved!.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        sc.Close();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're going to get better answers if you tell us what is wrong and what it should be doing. Try cutting your example down to just the barest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. That will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

ichramm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21069696/1346943) will most likely fix your problem, but you have some other issues at play here that may not be causing your error message, but are bad practice.

First, parameterize your queries so you are not susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities (I readily acknowledge that in your specific example that doesn't seem like a real risk, but it is better to always do things the right way):

```
string update = "UPDATE Weekdays SET Departure = @DepartureTime WHERE Arrival = @ArrivalDate;";
OleDbCommand read1 = new OleDbCommand(update, sc);
read1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartureTime", DateTime.Now);
read1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivalDate", dateList[0]);
...
```

Given your details, you probably don't need to worry about time zones, but I'd still suggest using `DateTime.UtcNow` than `DateTime.Now` because, again, it's a best practice to only store date/time values in UTC so you don't have to worry about figuring out what time zone your stored value is.

I'm assuming `sc` is an `OleDbConnection` object in your example code, so if that isn't true than you can ignore my references to it here. `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbConnection` implement the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. What this means is that these classes are set up to clean up after themselves if you instantiate them in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block, so I'd suggest reworking your code like this:

```
try
{
    using (var sc = new OleDbConnection("[YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING]"))
    {
        using (var read = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            read.Connection = sc;
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                //set up insert command
                //parameterize it
            }
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                //set up update command
                //see my suggestion above on how this should be parameterized
            }

            sc.Open();

            //your command doesn't return any results, so why use read.ExecuteReader()?
            //read.ExecuteNonQuery() will work fine for your purposes and doesn't instantiate
            //another object
            var rowsAffected = read.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        //at this point, regardless of whether you encounter an error, your command object is cleaned up
    }
    //now your connection is automatically closed/disposed of properly, again regardless of whether
    //you encounter an error
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Notice I've changed your `read.ExecuteReader()` to `read.ExecuteNonQuery()`: you don't need to use `ExecuteReader()` because your commands aren't returning a result set, so this way you avoid instantiating the `OleDbDataReader`.

Again, ichramm's answer should get you past your immediate issue, but I'd seriously consider the changes I've suggested here.

Answer (score 1):

```
string update = "UPDATE Weekdays SET Departure = '" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Arrival ='" +"';";
```

Shouldn't this be

```
string update = "UPDATE Weekdays SET Departure = '" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE Arrival ='" + dateList[0] "';";
```

Hint: I added `dateList[0]` to the condition